# jQuery event handler .on() not working

Tags: event-handling, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to attach a event to dynamically created element class.So i used live function but it was not triggered. So checked [live function reference](http://api.jquery.com/live/) ,there i red below notes

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

so decide to use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function,But it still not working.The text field is already attached with jquery ui datpicker.On another element select i disabled that field.

```
jQuery("#from").attr('disabled','disabled')
.removeClass('date_picker_bg')
.removeClass('hasDatepicker')
.addClass('date_picker_disabled');
```

after disabled if i click i want to show alert or tooltip.so i tried this,but not working

```
jQuery(".date_picker_disabled").on("click", function(event){
          alert('hi');
  });
```

What may be the problem

I am using jquery 1.7.1 ( jquery-1.7.1.min.js)

Comment: have you got a small jsfiddle to explain your problem a bit more

Comment: @Purmou:even live not working for me

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The problem is that `jQuery(".date_picker_disabled")` finds elements with that class and binds to them. If elements don't have the class at the time the binding is made, the events will not be handled.

The `on` function allows you to get round this by handling them on another element when the event "bubbles up to" a parent element. In this instance, we could say the `body` element – there may be a more specific common parent you could choose.

```
jQuery(document.body).on('click', '.date_picker_disabled', function(event) {
    alert('hi');
});
```

The event handler is now bound to the `document.body` element. All clicks that happen anywhere in the body are tested to see if they originated from an element matching the selector. If so, the handler is fired.

This is explained on the documentation for the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) function. It is the same behaviour as was present in previous versions of jQuery with `live` and `delegate` functions.

---

Having taken another look at your code, you have `disabled="disabled"` set on your `input` element. `click` events are not fired on disabled elements.

Comment: :Valid edit,Do you have any idea to this.can i trigger other event on disabled element.and one more doubt jQuery('document.body') is right or jQuery(document.body)

Comment: @gowri presumably you could put the disabled input tag in a `div` and bind the click event to the div.  Or you could make it readonly and style it the same as disabled (I am not sure if that stops the click event, but I would guess that it wouldn't)

Comment: `jQuery(document.body)` is the same as `jQuery('body')`. The former is quicker: basing a jQuery selection on a DOM element is the quickest possible method. I think `readonly` is probably the best solution for you.

Comment: It is also worth noting that if your "parent element" that your trying to apply this type of .on() to, has to exist when applying the .on(). Which means if your parent element is also dynamic, then go up the parent elements higher until you have a static element that is available at the time of apply .on().. I just ran into this issue..

Comment: Some parts of this explanation made things very clear to me about how `.on()` works, especially “allows you to get round this by handling them on another element _when the event "bubbles up to" a parent element_”. Very insightful. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This is tricky.

When your code runs, your element does not have `.date_picker_disabled` class so your `jQuery(".date_picker_disabled")` returns nothing and `.on()` is not called.

Apply .on() on the outer element and use the selector parameter:

```
// you can also do $(document).on()
$(<outer element>).on('click', '.date_picker_disabled', function() {
    // do something
});
```

This will delegate the event to the `<outer element>`. The handler will only be executed if an element with class `.date_picker_disabled` has been clicked (second param).

Comment: Please note that <outer element> shouldn't be a dynamically generated one!

Comment: @ijasnijas > I guess you simply mean that they must exist in the DOM when you make the call to `.on()`. Otherwise, they could be generated ones.

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation of [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> Rewriting the .live() method in terms of its successors is
>   straightforward; these are templates for equivalent calls for all
>   three event attachment methods:
>
> ```
> $(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
> $(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+ 
> $(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
> ```

So in your case, you would do:

```
$(document).on('click', '.date_picker_disabled', function(event){
    alert('hi');
});
```

Comment: This helps, but it took me a while to actually see the main point. You should emphasize it.

Answer (score 3):

I was using jQuery 1.7.2 and tried all proposed methods:

**Didn't work:**

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.collapsible-toggle'  function() {
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

**Didn't work:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.collapsible-toggle'  function() {
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

None of them worked until I tried the following:

**----- Worked! ----**

```
$('body .collapsible-toggle').on('click',   function() {
        console.log('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should do:

```
jQuery("body").on("click",".date_picker_disabled", function(event){
          alert('hi');
  });
```

in this way you attach the event handler to the bosy and specify to fire that event only when that selector ".date_picker_disabled" is matched.
BTW this is exactly how `live()` worked

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
$(document.body).on( "click", ".date_picker_disabled", function() {   
   alert('hi');
});
```

**document.body** helps for dynamic html too.
Just chekc it out: [.on not working on dynamic html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30230712/on-not-working-on-dynamic-html)