# Is there an "Update" function for jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

if we push Html to the `Dom` , it will be display there but its not updated. is there any update function to jQuery ?

```js
$(function(){
   $('#add').on('click', function(){
       $('.outer').append('<div class="data"><input type="text" value="enter" /><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></div>');
   });
   $('.remove').on('click', function(){
       alert('not working');
   });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="outer">
 <input type="button" value="Click me" id="add" />
</div><!-- /.outer -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Anchor link not working when we push to the `DOM` , every answers must be appreciated ?

Comment: You need to use backend service to store data. So, even if you refresh. The data will still be there.

Comment: no need backend , we can do it with javascript or jQuery via local storage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `$(document).on('click', '.remove'` instead:

```
$(function(){
   $(document).on('click', '#add', function(){
       $('.outer').append('<div class="data"><input type="text" value="enter" /><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></div>');
   });
   $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
       alert('not working');
   });
});
```

This way jQuery listens for `click` events on the document, and if the target element is `.remove` (for example) - the function will be triggered. It doesn't matter if the elements are added dynamically - the `click` event is always on the document, and jQuery will check the target element (and act accordingly).

Here is the update to your snippet:

```js
$(function(){
   $(document).on('click', '#add', function(){
       $('.outer').append('<div class="data"><input type="text" value="enter" /><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></div>');
   });
   $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
       alert('not working');
   });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="outer">
 <input type="button" value="Click me" id="add" />
</div><!-- /.outer -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can we update it to the dom , ( like do i refresh the page the contents not dissapear )

Comment: Actually - it is update in the dom. The problem is that the `event` was attached to all the **old** `.remove` elements (and the new `.remove` element that we just added don't have this event attached).

Comment: I'm not sure listening for Events on the document makes more sense, since code will run any time the document is clicked.

Comment: You can always set the listener on a specific container (in this example - the `.outer`). It will be `$('.outer').on('click', '.remove', function() { ...`

Answer (score 2):

You are attaching `click` event to element that does not exist in `document`.

You can use `jQuery()` to attach the event to the element when the element is dynamically created.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#add").on("click", function() {
    var div = $("<div>", {
      "class": "data",
      html: $("<input>", {
        type: "text",
        value: "enter"
      }),
      append: $("<a>", {
        href: "#",
        "class": "remove",
        html: "Remove",
        on: {
          click: function() {
            alert("not working");
          }
        }
      })
    })
    $(".outer").append(div);
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="outer">
    <input type="button" value="Click me" id="add" />
  </div>
  <!-- /.outer -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: nice one , i have never seen a code like this, its amazing

Comment: @JishnuVS See [`jQuery(html, attributes)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes)

Comment: I wanna study Javascript and jQuery , is there any tutorial to study the jQuery in top level

Comment: @JishnuVS You can browse [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com) , [`javascript`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript),  [`jquery`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) Questions and Answers, here at stackoverflow that you find interesting. See also [WebPlatform docs](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/Main_Page) ,  [Ecma TC39](https://github.com/tc39), and the specification [ECMAScript® 2017 Language Specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/)

Answer (score 1):

As per this question, I solved it by changing the line

$('.remove').on('click', function(){

to $('body').on('click','.remove', function(){

UPDATE: $('.outer').on('click','.remove', function(){

[jQuery event handler .on() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614981/jquery-event-handler-on-not-working)

```js
$(function(){
   $('#add').on('click', function(){
       $('.outer').append('<div class="data"><input type="text" value="enter" /><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></div>');
   });
   $('.outer').on('click','a.remove', function(){
       alert('not working');
   });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="outer">
 <input type="button" value="Click me" id="add" />
</div><!-- /.outer -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Basically attach the .on to an existing element then use the 2nd parameter to specify the "expected" elements. Of course this solution just makes it work and there are things you can do to make the event handler more specific like replacing document.body.

Comment: Why do you use `document.body` instead of parent element `.outer` to attach `click` event to?

Comment: Sorry, did a quick and dirty approach. That works too. It depends in what context you want the event to fire. I updated the answer with .outer as it seems it is the best context for this question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$('.remove')` is not defined at the time you attempt to assign an Event to it. Change

```
$(function(){
   $('#add').on('click', function(){
       $('.outer').append('<div class="data"><input type="text" value="enter" /><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></div>');
   });
   $('.remove').on('click', function(){
     alert('not working');;
   });
});
```

to

```js
$(function(){
  $('#add').click(function(){
    $('.outer').append("<div class='data'><input type='text' value='enter' /><a href='#' class='remove'>Remove</a></div>");       
    $('.remove').on('click', function(){
      $(this).parent().remove();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='outer'>
 <input type='button' value='Click me' id='add' />
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is really not good, because every time you *add* new button. you attach the `click` event to **all** the `.remove` elements (over and over). Basically if you click 5 times on `add` and then click on the first `remove` - you will get 5 alerts.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the issue here @Dekel ... I was a bit confused at the downvote initially

Comment: That won't matter, since each click adds the Event it will work just fine.

Comment: This is how we learn things :) (I hate when people just downvote with no reason). @PHPglue, please keep this answer (if you don't care) so people will be able to learn from the explanation.

Comment: As said - each click will add multiple events. This **is** a problem (if you ask me).

Comment: @PHPglue, check this link: https://jsfiddle.net/6cv5yk44/ click 3 times on the `click me` button and then click on the **first** (top) `remove link`. You will get 3 alerts.

Comment: I'm not sure which `$(this)` you refer to. I copy*paste your exact code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
   $('#add').on('click', function(){
       $('.outer').append('<div class="data"><input type="text" value="enter" /><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></div>');
   });
   $('.remove').on('click', function(){
       alert('not working');
   });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="outer">
 <input type="button" value="Click me" id="add" />
</div><!-- /.outer -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```