# Autocomplete w/Dynamic Table Jquery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, autocomplete

I have resolved a few things, and it works now, thanks to this page, they helped me in another thing. Now, this is how I got the code, and the Autocomplete works, but only I can  just with the ones that are loaded when the page is displayed, if I enter the first one, the autocomplete script puts the description, quantity and price of the code I entered, instead of just the first row, or the row I want to put the code in. This is my code right now.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //this is added just to pre-populate some rows
  addRow2('dataTable');



  $(".chkall").click(function() {
    if ($(".chkall").is(':checked')) {
      $("#dataTable input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
      });

    } else {
      $("#dataTable input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
      });
    }
  });


  $('.get_total, .g_total').click(function(e) {
    g_total = 0;
    $('input.total').each(function() {
      g_total += eval($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(g_total);
    $('.g_total').html(g_total);
  })
  $('input.total').on('change', function() {
    g_total = 0;
    $('input.total').each(function() {
      g_total += eval($(this).val());
      $('.g_total').html(g_total);
    })
  })
})

function grandTotal() {
  g_total = 0;
  $('input.total').each(function() {
    g_total += eval($(this).val());
    $('.g_total').html(g_total);
  })
}


function addRow2(tableid) {

  

  var table = $('#' + tableid);
  rowCount = table.children().length;
  //console.log(table.children().length);
  newrow = '<tr class="dataRow"><td><input type="checkbox" name="chkbox[]" class="remove"></td><td><input class="codigo" type="text" name="codigo[]"></td><td><input type="text" class="descripcion" name="descripcion[]"></td><td><input type="text" step="any" class="cantidad" min="1" onchange="calc2($(this))" name="cantidad[]"></td><td><input type="text" step="any" min="0" value="0" class="precio" name="precio[]" onchange="calc2($(this));"></td><td><input type="text"  value="0" class="total" name="total[]"></td></tr>';
  table.append(newrow);

  $("#dataTable input[id^='codigo']").autocomplete({
    source:'buscarcompra.php',
    minLength:1
});

  $("#dataTable input[id^='codigo']").focusout(function(){
  $.ajax({
        url:'producto.php',
      type:'POST',
      dataType:'json',
      data:{ codigo: $("#dataTable input[id^='codigo']").val()}
  }).done(function(respuesta){
       $("#dataTable input[name^='descripcion']").val(respuesta.descripcion);
       $("#dataTable input[name^='precio']").val(respuesta.precio);
  });
});
}



function calc2(_row) {
  row = _row.closest('.dataRow');
  //console.log();
  //
  qty = row.find('.cantidad').val();
  price = row.find('.precio').val();
  total = parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(price);
  console.log('qty:' + qty + ' * price:' + price + ' = ' + total);
  row.closest('.dataRow').find('.total').val(total);
  grandTotal();
}



function deleteRow(tableID) {
  try {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      var row = table.rows[i];
      var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
      if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
        i--;
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

```css
.g_total {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
.cantidad,
.precio,
.total {
  /*
  height: 50px;
  width: 40px;*/
  text-align: center;
}
.cantidad {
  width: 84px;
}
.codigo,
.descripcion {
  width: 54px
}
.precio,
.total {
  width: 121px;
}
```

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<h1>CARRITO DE COMPRAS</h1>
<INPUT type="button" value="Agregar Producto" onClick="addRow2('dataTable')" />

<INPUT type="button" value="Borrar Producto" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
<input type="button" class="get_total" value="Get Total" />
<form id="myform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']  ?>" method="post">



  <TABLE border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <input type="checkbox" class="chkall">
        </th>
        <th class="codigo">CODIGO</th>
        <th class="descripcion">DESCRIPCION</th>
        <th class="cantidad">CANTIDAD</th>
        <th class="precio">PRECIO</th>
        <th class='total'>TOTAL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="dataTable">

    </tbody>
  </TABLE>
  </div>
  </br>
  <div class="g_total">
    </span>
```

Comment: Are you trying to attach `.autocomplete()` to each dynamically created `<input>` element?

Comment: I want to have an autocomplete for each one. Because I want to have the description, and quantity and the price of the product I want. (The calculate method works fine). I just don't know how am I going to implement it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function to attach `.autocomplete()` and `.focusout()` events to `:last` `.codigo` element at `.ready()` handler and `addRow` function call. Substituted `+` operator for `eval()` calls.

```js
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
];

$(document).ready(function() {

  //this is added just to pre-populate some rows
  addRow2('dataTable');

  addAutocompleteAndFocusout("#dataTable input[class^='codigo']", availableTags);

  $(".chkall").click(function() {
    if ($(".chkall").is(':checked')) {
      $("#dataTable input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
      });

    } else {
      $("#dataTable input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
      });
    }
  });


  $('.get_total, .g_total').click(function(e) {
    g_total = 0;
    $('input.total').each(function() {
      g_total += +$(this).val();
    });
    console.log(g_total);
    $('.g_total').html(g_total);
  })

  $('input.total').on('change', function() {
    g_total = 0;
    $('input.total').each(function() {
      g_total += +$(this).val();
      $('.g_total').html(g_total);
    })
  })
})

function addAutocompleteAndFocusout(selector, src) {
  (typeof selector === "string" ? $(selector) : selector).autocomplete({
      source: src
    })
    .focusout(function() {
      console.log("focusout called")
    })
}

function grandTotal() {
  g_total = 0;
  $('input.total').each(function() {
    g_total += +$(this).val();
    $('.g_total').html(g_total);
  })
}


function addRow2(tableid) {
  var table = $('#' + tableid);
  rowCount = table.children().length;
  newrow = '<tr class="dataRow"><td><input type="checkbox" name="chkbox[]" class="remove"></td><td><input class="codigo" type="text" name="codigo[]"></td><td><input type="text" class="descripcion" name="descripcion[]"></td><td><input type="text" step="any" class="cantidad" min="1" onchange="calc2($(this))" name="cantidad[]"></td><td><input type="text" step="any" min="0" value="0" class="precio" name="precio[]" onchange="calc2($(this));"></td><td><input type="text"  value="0" class="total" name="total[]"></td></tr>';
  table.append(newrow);
  // attach `.autocomplete()`, `.focusout()` to `:last` `.codigo` element
  addAutocompleteAndFocusout(table.find(".codigo:last"), availableTags);
}

function calc2(_row) {
  row = _row.closest('.dataRow');
  qty = row.find('.cantidad').val();
  price = row.find('.precio').val();
  total = parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(price);
  console.log('qty:' + qty + ' * price:' + price + ' = ' + total);
  row.closest('.dataRow').find('.total').val(total);
  grandTotal();
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
  try {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      var row = table.rows[i];
      var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
      if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
        i--;
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

```css
.g_total {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
.cantidad,
.precio,
.total {
  /*
  height: 50px;
  width: 40px;*/
  text-align: center;
}
.cantidad {
  width: 84px;
}
.codigo,
.descripcion {
  width: 54px
}
.precio,
.total {
  width: 121px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<h1>CARRITO DE COMPRAS</h1>
<INPUT type="button" value="Agregar Producto" onClick="addRow2('dataTable')" />

<INPUT type="button" value="Borrar Producto" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
<input type="button" class="get_total" value="Get Total" />
<form id="myform" action="" method="post">
  <TABLE border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <input type="checkbox" class="chkall">
        </th>
        <th class="codigo">CODIGO</th>
        <th class="descripcion">DESCRIPCION</th>
        <th class="cantidad">CANTIDAD</th>
        <th class="precio">PRECIO</th>
        <th class='total'>TOTAL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="dataTable">

    </tbody>
  </TABLE>
  <br/>
  <div class="g_total">

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Tried it, or I didn't quite understood it, or it didn't work.

Comment: @RafaelHernandez Replace `cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='codigo[]' name='codigo[]'>";` with `$(cell2).html($("<input>", {type:"text",id:"codigo[]", name:"codigo[]"}).autocomplete(/*autocomple options*/))`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/40986561/

Comment: Negative. That also didn't work :( I replaced it, in the .autocomplete()) and .focusout(function(){} and   data:{ codigo: [here].val()}, but, with no success, but thanks.

Comment: I modified my code, I've put the autocomplete into the addRow, it works, in a way, it just completes all of the other rows instead of just one.

Comment: You are attaching the `.autocomplete()` method and `.focusout()` event to the elements multiple times at each call to `addRow2()`. You can either use pattern at `javascript` at Answer, which attaches the event to the dynamically created element itself, or use event delegation.

Comment: Hello, again, I've been trying to put any of those, but I can't seem to find the solution. I know that, since it has the same ID, it fills every other row with the same code.

Comment: _"since it has the same ID"_ Are there more than one element having same `id` at `html`? `id` of element within `document` should be unique.

Comment: As far as I know, when I add another row, it creates an input with the same id of the row, ie: cantidad, precio, nombre, codigo. What I understand is that, I need to find a way, once I have a new row added, I can type the code, and it'll show the one I type, because it's only showing the first one.

Comment: @RafaelHernandez The `html` at updated Question contains syntax errors. You can echo ajax calls at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @RafaelHernandez Note, was incorrect earlier about `.focusout()` method of jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, it does work, but not in the way I have wanted it. Since I'm using the autocomplete for an outside source for a query in MySQL, I put the code in, and it'll insert the description and price on the corresponding rows, I've mold it in a way where I can still use the autocomplete the way I want to, but, it still adds every other row with the first code I've write. I'll still gonna work to try and find a solution.

Comment: _"it does work, but not in the way I have wanted it. Since I'm using the autocomplete for an outside source for a query in MySQL"_ You can change the `source` of `.autocomplete()`. The `javascript` at Answer is to demonstrate the pattern. _"it still adds every other row with the first code I've write"_ Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Yeah, that's how I modified it, and it works in a way. 
Let's say I have 5 products in a MySQL table products, with code name as 1,2,3,4. 
Every code has a unique description, and price. Ex 1 has 10, 2 has 30 
When I want to put the code name 1, it does fill both inputs[description, and price] correctly, but, if I add another row, and put code 2, the inputs of description and price are filled the same as code name 1, and not 2.

Comment: Not sure follow, though you can pass different path for `source` of each `.autocomplete()` instance at second parameter to `addAutocompleteAndFocusout` function within `addRow`. `addAutocompleteAndFocusout("#dataTable input[class^='codigo']", availableTags)`

Comment: I understand now. I edited the availableTags like this: 
var availableTags =  { source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
               url:'producto.php',
          type:'POST',
          dataType:'json',
                 data:{ codigo: $("#dataTable input[class^='codigo']").val()}
            }).done(function(respuesta){
           $("#dataTable input[name^='descripcion']").val(respuesta.descripcion);
           $("#dataTable input[name^='precio']").val(respuesta.precio);
      });
        },
        minLength: 2,

      };

Though, it won't work :/

Comment: There are multiple `.codigo`, `[name=description]`, `[name=precio]`  elements in `document`. You can pass the current dynamically created elements to the function as parameters. Also, you mentioned different `url`'s which you are calling, yes? Why do you use only `producto.php`?

Comment: That's where I have the mysql script for searching the producto, the other one 'buscarproducto.php' is only for searching what code it is. Since the code is only 6 characters long, it isn't that much required for having a search for the individual codigo.