# button generated by jquery not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a form with a button that is able to create new input text field and a button using jquery. Then I have a problem with the button that is newly generated, it is unable to call a jquery action.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('.add').click(function () {
          $('#more').append('<input type=text />');
          $('#more').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button>');
       });
    
       $('.remove').click(function(){
            alert('this text field should be removed');
       })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary add" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
    <div id="more"></div>
```

When `add` button is clicked, it does append new input text and the button. But this new button with `remove` class is unable to trigger thing when it's clicked. Anyone can find what I miss here?

Comment: The remove click event handler is applied when the code is executed, presumably before you click the add button. Since, at the time of execution, the new buttons do not exist, the event handler is not bound to them.

Comment: Use `$(.'remove').on('click', ...` and this should work. Read about direct and delegated events [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an "Update" function for jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40986460/is-there-an-update-function-for-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.on` will attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

`.click` will attach the events to the controls that already exist in the document.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.add').click(function() {
    $('#more').append('<input type=text />');
    $('#more').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>Remove</button>');
  });

  $('#more').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    alert('this text field should be removed');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary add" type="button">Add<i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
<div id="more"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `$('.remove').click(function()...)` inside the `$('.add').click(function(){ ... })`.

The current scripts only filters the `.remove` elements on the page when the page is loaded.

Comment: yes, it's working. but I'd prefer Sankar's answer. thanks anyway.